# Avoid form action call to php file from loading new page

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, call

I have a form that's calling a Post a .php file, which i though was the basis of ajax pushing (as opposed to retrieving data with ajax). Unfortunately, my browser will always load my called .php file instead of staying on the page containing the form. I' thinking there's a specific line of code I'm forgetting somewhere. What should I be looking for?

```
<form id="form-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="_scripts/ajax/cropImage.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();" style="min-height:450px; position:relative;">
                    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="ht" name="ht" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="wt" name="wt" />
                    <div style="position:absolute">
                    <h2>Upload a picture</h2>
                    <input id="input-upload" name="input-upload" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /><br/>
                    <img id="upload-preview" src="" alt="" />
                    <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="$('#fancybox-close').trigger('click');"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <img id="spinner" style="position:absolute; background-color:transparent; left:49%; top:50%;" src="_images/uploads/ajax-loader.gif" height="32" width="32"/>
                </form>
```

Comment: Please provide some of your code, specifically the form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your understanding of AJAX is a little wrong, don't take me wrong, I suggest you to read more about it and try to implment it using [Jquery libraries for Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). Those functions are very well documented and have great examples.

I would not use form tag while using ajax.

This is an example function you would use when use "submit" the data:

```
$.post("_scripts/ajax/cropImage.php", { 
                                       "y": yValue, 
                                       "x": xValue, 
                                       "h": hValue, 
                                          ...
                                       "input-upload": inputUploadValue
                                      });
```

Explaining: You will send all values at the object ("y", "x", etc) to "_scripts/ajax/cropImage.php", as POST variables. You can also create a callback function, to receive data from the URL you sended those values, and validate if everything ran well.

*It seems you're using the action attribute of your Form and submiting it. Show us all your related code, please.* (Text before showing the code)

Comment: yes i am using the action attribute of my form. Should I be calling the other .php through javascript? I think that's the solution to it.

Comment: You **must** use Javascript. AJAX stands for Asynchronous **Javascript** and XML

Answer (score 0):

You can post data the same way you can retrieve data with jquery's ajax library.

See the [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.

You can get the contents of your input fields and then send them with ajax. If you want to keep your current form structure, you can use doSubmit(); return false; in an onsubmit event to cancel the original submit, and use your ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a submit type button.
Change the type to "button", and make the onclick event something like:

```
onclick="sendData();"
```

Your sendData() function should contain the proper AJAX.
I see you are using jQuery, so just use the built-in ajax functions:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "_scripts/ajax/cropImage.php",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(html){
    alert(html);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {  
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below  
   var comment = $('#comments').val();  
   var name = $('#Name').val();

           $.ajax({  
               type: "POST",  
               url: "contactus.php",
              // data: "fname="+ fname +"& lname="+ lname,  
               data: "name="+ name +"& comment="+ comment,  
               success: function(response){ 
                $('#mail_sent').html(response);    
               }  
           });
      });
```